# Return a count of each distinct value as a column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write an SQL select statement which will return a column with each distinct value and another column specifying the amount of times that this distinct value occurs. I've tried the count function but can't figure it out.

The data looks something like:
(can't figure out how to write a table)

name: adam, adam, tim, tom

And I'd want to return:

name: adam, tim, tom

count: 2, 1, 1

edit: row -> column

Comment: Please supply examples to demonstrate the data you are working with and the results you desire.  Also, when you have code that hasn't worked, please include it as an example of what you have tried.  (Including any error messages, and/or details of what you mean by "can't get it working the way I need".)

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please give us some example input and desired output. Or the answer is so simple as juergen d showed.

Comment: @PetarRepac It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by the column you want to be distinct, then use `count` on that group

```
select col1, count(*) as amount
from your_table
group by col1
```